# Angular - How to show an input based on Dropdown option

Tags: html, angular

I wish to show the input field when "Others" option is selected on dropdown, but can't figure out how to-

Here is my code

```
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="college">College:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="college" ngModel name="college_name" required>
        <option>Ajay Kumar Garg Engineering College</option>
        <option>Others- Please Specify Below</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="showfield">
      <label for="name">Enter College Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ngModel name="other_college_name" required>
    </div>
```

showfield = false; is set in .ts file

Comment: @D.Simon You got me wrong, My purpose is to set that automatically based on option selection

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your component take a variable,

**`selectedValue: string = '';`**

Just assign `selectedvalue` to `ngModel` and use that value to display text field.

Also, options needs `value attribute` and it needs value to store in `ngModel`

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="college">College:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="college" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="college_name" required>
        <option value="college">Ajay Kumar Garg Engineering College</option>
        <option value="others">Others- Please Specify Below</option>
      </select>
 </div>
    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="selectedValue == 'others'">
      <label for="name">Enter College Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ngModel name="other_college_name" required>
    </div>
```

Comment: just a note, you will need to create the variable `selectedValue` inside the `*.component.ts` file.

Comment: yes thats obviously needed, let me add that to be more precise.

Comment: Yup, just mentioning it because the OP didn't know about `[(ngModel)]`, just covering all the bases :)

Comment: Actually you don't need to. You can bind a variable to ngModel and use it only in the HTML ! I often do that with checkboxes.

Comment: @Sravan never said otherwise. I'm just stating the fact that you don't **need to** do so.

Comment: @trichetriche, your answer seems to be same as mine. :)

Comment: @Sravan never said otherwise too. I also told the OP to upvote **one of the answers** since they're all good. I'm just telling you that you don't **need to** instantiate a vairable in the component.

Comment: How can we do the same in reactive form?  Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

You can do like so

```
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="college">College:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="college" [(ngModel)]="collegeName" name="college_name" required>
        <option value="AKGEC">Ajay Kumar Garg Engineering College</option>
        <option value="other">Others- Please Specify Below</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" *ngIf="collegeName === 'other'">
      <label for="name">Enter College Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ngModel name="other_college_name" required>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm

Comment: No problem, mark at least one of the answers as resolved !

Answer (score 0):

Your options must have a value associated with them, the selected options value will get set to the model associated with your dropdown select. You can check that for show/hide as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="college">College:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="college" [(ngModel)]="selectedVal" name="college_name" required>
            <option value="ajay">Ajay Kumar Garg Engineering College</option>
            <option value="others">Others- Please Specify Below</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" *ngIf="selectedVal==='others'">
          <label for="name">Enter College Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ngModel name="other_college_name" required>
</div>
```